# Creating a Jquery Fade effect

Tags: jquery, fadein

I am tweaking a plugin I have to change it from a sliding effect to a fade.

On rollover it currently slides a caption div into view. I need to make it so this fades into view and I am stuck (I am no JS programmer sadly, and normally can tweak. but I am stuck)

The old JS code was as below and moved a div up 106pxs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function(){
                $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'15px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
            }, function() {
                $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'106px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
            });
        });
```

But I cannot workout how to change the effect to a fadeIn on rollover and fadeOut on rollover. I would put my code but it is so poor and doesnt work. I can sort the CSS out to change the opacity etc.

Comment: I'd like to see some html along with this if possible. You should post all javascript / html / css related questions using http://jsfiddle.net/ makes it easy for everyone.

Comment: `fadeIn on rollover and fadeOut on rollover.` you want both on same event.

Comment: well he meant mouseleave of course...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function(){
        $(".cover", this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        })
    }, function() {
        $(".cover", this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 0.4
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this is great, my only issue is that it only seems to work once I have rolled over and then rolled out. So what happens is the overlay does nothing (if I have it set to opacity: 0.2) until I haved moused over it and thne removed my mouse from it. Once I have done that it works perfectly. However if I set the opacity to 0 then  it doesnt seem to work at all? Is there maybe a way to go from Opacity 0.2 to opacity 1 so the overlay is slightly visible and becomes darker on mouseover

Comment: Thankyou David - that's ace. The CSS one is great but I need some capatability back to old broswers. However the JS one causes a flashing in and out when rolled over, a sort of flashing? does it need a stop command?

Comment: yes sorry add stop() before the two animate() calls. I did realize it but was too late to edit :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple mouseover mouseout to fadein and fadeout then use this way:

```
$('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function(){
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({opacity:'1'},{queue:false,duration:160});
}, function() {
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({opacity:'0'},{queue:false,duration:160});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.boxgrid.caption').on('mouseover',function(){
        $(".cover", this).fadeIn();
    }).on('mouseout',function() {
        $(".cover", this).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Read `mouserover` and `mouseout` http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/
and http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Also for `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ and http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: the hover handler he is using is perfectly fine

Comment: This is another option if op thinks its better to use.